# FineUploader uploads the same file multiple times at the same time

Tags: fine-uploader

Say I want to upload several files at once, which is something I can do when setting the multiple option to true:

```
var myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#test')[0],
    multiple: true,
    request: { endpoint: 'path/to/master/server/php/' },
    autoUpload: false,
});
```

Now, let's say I have a button that will allow me to select the files I want to upload. If I click said button and select, say, test.txt file, test.txt will be added to the list of files that will be uploaded. So far so good. Now, my problem is that, if I click the button again, and select test.txt file again, it will be added to the list even though it's already in the list.

Is there any way to prevent FineUploader from letting me do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added an answer.  Also, please ensure you don't have any trailing commas in your code.  IE7 will barf if it encounters these.

Comment: @RayNicholus thank you for your answer Ray. I want you to know that I did upgrade the library to its latest version, and as you said, everything worked just fine (except for some css rules that I modified, hehe).

So far I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cotoadvance/6NgqE/

It works fine, but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert null to object` when I use the `reset` function.

Comment: Jose - The issue pops up when Fine Uploader attempts to finish handling the upload after your handler returns, but your handler calls `reset` which wipes out any state associated with that file.  Can you [open up a bug report](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) in the Github project so we can discuss this a bit more?  The error shouldn't cause any issues for you, but it should be dealt with.  I'd like to find out more about why you are calling `reset` here as well.  Also, please mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be careful declaring a file a duplicate simply based on the name.  You should also take size into account, at least.  Although, this is not possible in IE9 and older since we can't determine file size client-side in those browsers.  Just for the purposes of simplicity, let's use the file name exclusively...

One way is to maintain an array of file names submitted to the uploader.  You can add to this list in your an `onSubmitted` handler.  The, you can contribute an `onValidate` handler that will reject the file if it already exists in the array.  Your code would look something like this:

```js
var filenames = [];
var myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#test')[0],
    multiple: true,
    request: { endpoint: 'path/to/master/server/php/' },
    autoUpload: false,
    callbacks: {
        onSubmitted: function(id, name) {
            filenames.push(name);
        },
        onValidate: function(fileData) {
            return qq.indexOf(filenames, fileData.name) < 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Also, just for kicks, why not just use Fine Uploader's jQuery plug-in, since you seems to already be using jQuery in your project? The above example is rewritten using the jQuery plug-in below:

```js
var filenames = [];
$('#test').fineUploader({
    multiple: true,
    request: { endpoint: 'path/to/master/server/php/' },
    autoUpload: false
})
    .on("submitted", function(event, id, name) {
        filenames.push(name);    
    })
    .on("validate", function(event, fileData) {
        return $.inArray(fileData.name, filenames) < 0;
    });
```

Comment: @jk-jk I'm not sure who rejected your edit (it wasn't me), but it was perfectly valid, so I've edited the post according to your suggested edit (I also added syntax highlighting).  Thanks for catching that (reversed `$.inArray` params).

Comment: This code cancels all files if one of them is duplicate.. How can I cancel only the duplicate file but let other selected files auto upload normally?

Comment: @Alph.Dev This code will only cancel duplicate files.

Comment: I've found it. `stopOnFirstInvalidFile: false` did the trick. It's set to `true` by default...